# WooCommerce hook into coupon validation by user meta

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-hook

i'm searching for the hook where i can hook into the coupon validation during the checkout process.

Instead of validation by user's email address i would like to validate the coupon code by an user's meta field.

If the restricted coupon code matches the user meta field the discount is valid, otherwise coupon can't added to cart.

Which hook can i use?

Answer (score 3):

The hook you are looking for is [woocommerce_coupon_is_valid](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_coupon_is_valid/)

It's a filter running after all default coupon validations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this hook : woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product

You can get logged in user's information from wordpress and validate product there based on user meta information.

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product',  $false,  $product,  $instance,  $values );
```

It will give you 4 parameters when you implement it.